# Auto increment is not working on model

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core

I use entity framework core and mysql database.

My model looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to add a user I get `Field 'Id' doesn't have a default value`

```
var user = new User {
    Name = "Whatever"
};

_dbContext.Users.Add(user);
_dbContext.SaveChanges(); // Throws exception
```

And when I debug it I can see that my user's id value is `-2147482647`

```
InnerException  {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Field 'Id' doesn't have a default value
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.ActivateResultSet(ResultSet resultSet)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.<ReadFirstResultSetAsync>d__62.MoveNext()
```

I tried using `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` and `[Key]`, but it didn't do anything.
My generated migration looks like this:

```
    [DbContext(typeof(TetrominoContext))]
    [Migration("20170625090637_SixthMigration")]
    partial class SixthMigration
    {
        protected override void BuildTargetModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder
                .HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "1.1.2");

            modelBuilder.Entity("Tetromino.Models.User", b =>
                {
                    b.Property<int>("Id")
                        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

                    b.Property<string>("Name")
                        .IsRequired();

                    b.HasKey("Id");

                    b.ToTable("Users");
                });
        }
    }
```

My packages:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="1.1.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

After looking at my database it looks like entity framework doesn't set field `Id` as auto-incremental, but I can't find a way to force it.

I recreated my database to see if it would help, but the error still occurs, so I suspect that I have to modify migration somehow.

Comment: also declare `b.HasKey("Id");` on top

Comment: @Valkyriee I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: This is the first time I see migration like this. Are you using some EF Core v2 prelease version?

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm not sure. I updated my question.

Comment: The version is 1.1.2
It looks like a bug in MySQL provider as it should set up Id with some value generator (or auto-increment if that is supported). Please raise a bug on their provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to people at pomelo's github I was able to solve the problem. It turns out that I had to remove all of my previous migrations. For those who have the same problem.

1. In vs's package manager do: `Update-Database 0` (you have to go back
   to first migration to be able to remove previous one's)
2. Remove all migrations with: `Remove-Migration`
3. Create new migration: `Add-Migration migrationName`
4. Update db: `Update-Database`

Also you don't need `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` nor `[Key]`.

Comment: See the following SQLite discussion for more information: https://sqlite.org/forum/info/275b73944de964f8