# Test fails with SQLite Error 1: 'AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlite, unit-testing, .net-core

I have an .Net Core 6 application that use SQL server as the database.  During testing I spin-up an in-memory instance of SQLite for testing custom DB context methods.  This was all working and I went into the change some RESTful API, and now I am getting the following error:

> ApplicationDbContext_DuplicateCreateCompany_Test
>  Source: ApplicationDbContext_UnitTests.cs line 122   Message: 
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 1: 'AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY'.

If one goes to the bottom of the of the Test Explorer, I see he following message.

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE TABLE "IncidentNote" (
          "IncidentNoteId" bigint NOT NULL CONSTRAINT "PK_IncidentNote" PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
          "NoteTypeId" int NOT NULL,
          "Note" nvarchar NOT NULL,
          "CreatedDate" datetime2 NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT "FK_IncidentNote_NoteType_NoteTypeId" FOREIGN KEY ("NoteTypeId") REFERENCES "NoteType" ("NoteTypeId") ON DELETE RESTRICT
      );
```

I have remove all migrations and created a new initial migration as per the following:
[Auto increment is not working on model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44744943/auto-increment-is-not-working-on-model)

I even found the following forum post:
https://sqlite.org/forum/info/275b73944de964f8

I have found the following github issue:
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10228

When I include

```
  using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite;
```

it could not find .UseAutoincrement(false)

The following is the entity class:

```
  [Table("IncidentNote")]
  public partial class IncidentNote
  {
    [Key]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "IncidentNoteId is required.")]
    public long IncidentNoteId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "NoteTypeId is required.")]
    public int NoteTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Note is required."), MaxLength(1073741823, ErrorMessage = "'Note' must be 1073741823 or less characters.")]
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    //
    public virtual NoteType NoteType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<IncidentIncidentNote> IncidentIncidentNotes { get; }
      = new List<IncidentIncidentNote>();
    //
    public IncidentNote()
    {
      IncidentNoteId = 0;
      NoteTypeId = 0;
      Note = "";
      CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
  }
```

The following is the entity class configuration:

```
  public class IncidentNoteConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<IncidentNote>
  {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<IncidentNote> builder)
    {
      builder.ToTable("IncidentNote");
      // propteries
      builder.HasKey(i => i.IncidentNoteId);
      builder.Property(i => i.IncidentNoteId)
        .UseIdentityColumn<long>(1, 1)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("IncidentNoteId")
        .HasColumnType("bigint");
      builder.Property(i => i.NoteTypeId)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("NoteTypeId")
        .HasColumnType("int");
      builder.Property(i => i.Note)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasMaxLength(1073741823)
        .HasColumnName("Note")
        .HasColumnType("nvarchar");
      builder.Property(i => i.CreatedDate)
        .IsRequired()
        .HasColumnName("CreatedDate")
        .HasColumnType("datetime2");
      // indexes
      builder.HasIndex(i => i.NoteTypeId)
        .HasDatabaseName("IX_IncidentNote_NoteTypeId");
      // relationships
      builder.HasMany(iin => iin.IncidentIncidentNotes)
        .WithOne(s => s.IncidentNote)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.IncidentNoteId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_IncidentIncidentNotes_IncidentNote_IncidentNoteId");
      builder.HasOne(ft => ft.NoteType)
        .WithMany(i => i.IncidentNotes)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.NoteTypeId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_IncidentNote_NoteType_NoteTypeId");
    } // Configure
  } // IncidentNoteConfiguration
```

In my option the AUTOINCREMENT is code generated by Microsoft incorrectly, because SQLite AUTOICREMENT is very very different from Identity(1,1).  But what to do to get  the test working again?

Comment: Based on this [commit](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/pull/22245/commits/e185c525a4d49f82c4322515a5dcc7e239d7a062) you can try `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` or `.ValueGeneratedNever()`

Comment: Sorry, I tried both and migrated and did not help.  The MS code generation is still adding the AUTOINCREMENT to the SQL Server identity column.

Comment: Does anybody know how to use .UseAutoincrement(false) that is referenced in SQLite: Make AUTOINCREMENT more first-class #10228: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10228

Comment: ...`UseAutoincrement` is just a proposal. I tried to use `DatabaseGenerated` myself, and I could see the `Sqlite:Autoincrement` annotation was removed in the new migration file. In case you use it wrong, the attribute should be placed above `public long IncidentNoteId`.

Comment: I noticed that you used `UseIdentityColumn`, it exists in SqlServer, but I couldn't find it in Sqlite.

Comment: I have a partial solution, but not the one I was hoping.  I can create a SQL Server table with a BIGINT identity and a SQLite table with an INTEGER key.  In the entity class, I used the attribute `[Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` on the **long** key.  In the EntityTypeBuilder, I only used `item.HasKey(i => i.IncidentNoteId);`. I had no property for the column.  Basically, you need to leave out the `.HasColumnType("bigint")`.  Now, I will have foreign keys that are BIGINT and the corresponding primary key will be INTEGER.  Not very good.

Comment: Additionally, the EntityTypeBuilder for the Note property, I removed both  `.HasMaxLength(1073741823)` and `.HasColumnType("nvarchar");`.  It is relying on the declaration of the entity class.  Otherwise, I got `The size (1073741823) given to the column 'entity' exceeds the maximum allowed for any data type (8000).` error message